# Spring ioc interface and implementation in different package

Tags: java, spring, configuration, inversion-of-control

I have two packages

- com.xxx.A contains a interface - > persistence.
- com.xxx.B contains several impls for persistence,

  - etc. mySqlPersistence, hibernatePersistence.

My question is when I using spring IOC to switch different implementation, how can I config them? by the way I using constructor inject..

NOTE: Currently,

- In package "A" I have a repository to use persistence interface.
- The implementation in package "B"
- since the impl meed operate domain which belongs Package "A" then Package "B" depend on package "A".

where the config file should be?

First time to touch java spring, thanks for help....

Comment: When do you want to change implementations? On different deployments? On application start? On the fly?

Comment: @RobertMoskal should be on application start choose different impl.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting below in web.xml/configuration.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>hibernatePersistence</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>mySqlPersistence</param-value>
</context-param-->
```

The components which are related to hibernate can be annotated as:

```
@ActiveProfiles("hibernatePersistence")
```

And similarly you can have components for "mySqlPersistence"

If you need mySqlPersistence to be active remove the comments and comment "hibernatePersistence" one.

Comment: thanks, this solution will change source code when I switch different impl?

Comment: Your implementations should be such that components/classes should be different for hibernate and mysql (recognized by @ActiveProfiles). And when you want to switch,just comment the profile in XML file which you don't need.